# Can a concept be checked against incomplete type

Tags: c++, c++20, c++-concepts

I stumbled upon this:

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <concepts>

template<class T>
concept IsFoo = requires(T a)
{
    {a.a} -> std::same_as<int>;
};

#if 1
// Will not compile, because Foo currently has incomplete type
template<IsFoo AFoo>
struct AcceptsFoo
{};
#else
template<class AFoo>
struct AcceptsFoo
{};
#endif

struct Foo
{
    int a;
    int b;

    AcceptsFoo<Foo> obj;
};
```

https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/j43s4z

Other variant (crtp) https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/GoWfhq

Foo is incomplete because it has to instantiate `AcceptsFoo`, but to do so, `Foo` has to be complete, otherwise it cannot check `IsFoo`. Is this a bug in GCC, or does the standard say so? The latter would be sad, because this prevents concepts for being used together with some well-known patterns such as CRTP.

I noticed that clang does gives a similar error: https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/d5bEez

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can *check* a concept against an incomplete type - but if that concept check requires actually doing anything with the type that requires it to complete, that's going to fail the concept check.

And even there, you have to be careful since implementations are allowed to (and will) cache concept checks to compile faster - so if you try `C<T>` while `T` is incomplete and try again when `T` becomes complete, and those should give different answers, you're asking for trouble.

`Foo` isn't complete at the point you're checking it, so naturally it doesn't have a member named `a`. This really cannot possibly work.

> because this prevents concepts for being used together with some well-known patterns such as CRTP.

Being used together *in this way*, yes. In the same way that with CRTP you also can't access anything directly off of the template parameter passed into the base class, you always have to be careful to delay any instantiation of that type until it is complete.

This is ultimately the same reason:

```cpp
template <typename Derived>
struct B { 
    typename Derived::type x;
};

struct D : B<D> {
    using type = int;
};
```

does not work.

Comment: *"so **naturally** it doesn't have a member named `a`"* (emphasis mine). For some parts (maybe indeed only in class definition), *"under definition"* can see part already defined (but not later) (I already had to move members from bottom to top to fix code (`auto` return type for example)). So it might be reasonable (even if wrong) that `AcceptsFoo<Foo>` see already defined members. (CRTP would have issue that it is the first part of definition, so couldn't see anything anyway).

Comment: @Jarod42 [Class member access requires the class to be complete.](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.ref#4.sentence-2)

Comment: "so if you try C<T> while T is incomplete and try again when T becomes complete, and those should give different answers, you're asking for trouble."
This seems like standard is looking for trouble, why even allow concept check on incomplete type if full type can give different result? In other words: is there any use case where this helps?

Comment: @NoSenseEtAl It's not a question of complete vs incomplete - there are lots of things that can change about a type between one point in a program. If you have a concept checking for like... `foo(t)` then `HasFoo<T>` might be `false` at one point and then an overload is added and then it becomes `true`. Complete/Incomplete is just one example of that, and likely not the most common one.

Answer (score -1):

[EDIT] This works as expected on g++ 10.3, 11.2 and current clang. Some comments indicate that this is undefined behavior, so beware of possibly unexpected changes for future compilers.

Original solution:

I also just stumbled on this, and succeeded in making my CRTP with concepts work by allowing type to be either incomplete, or complete with the desired constraints.

Besides the defined `IsFoo`, I also define `IsComplete` helper (using `sizeof` trick) and, finally, `IsFooIncomplete` in the following way:

```
template<class T> 
concept IsFooIncomplete = !IsComplete<T> || IsFoo<T>;
```

This way I can ensure that, during the processing of Foo, it is incomplete, and just after class is finished, it is complete and matches desired `IsFoo` constraints.

```
#include <concepts>
#include <type_traits>

template<class T>
concept IsFoo = requires(T self)
{
   {
      self.a
      } -> std::same_as<int&>;
};

template<class T>
concept IsComplete = requires(T self)
{
   {
      // You can't apply sizeof to an incomplete type
      sizeof(self)
   };
};

template<class T>
concept IsFooIncomplete = !IsComplete<T> || IsFoo<T>;

#if 0
// Will not compile, because Foo currently has incomplete type
template<IsFoo AFoo>
struct AcceptsFoo
{};
#else
// will compile with IsFooIncomplete
template<IsFooIncomplete AFoo> // no need to use 'class AFoo' here...
struct AcceptsFoo
{};
#endif

struct Foo
{
   int a;
   int b;

   // Foo is incomplete here, but that's fine!
   static_assert(!IsComplete<Foo>);
   AcceptsFoo<Foo> obj;
};

// Foo is now complete, and that's also fine!
static_assert(IsFoo<Foo>);
```

Works fine on `g++` version `10.3.0` (with flag `--std=c++20`), and I hope it works on other compilers as well.

[EDIT] as pointed out in comments, this accepts any incomplete type, but thats intended. Only the external static assert will filter complete type cases. Thanks @David Herring for the example on Bar, I wrote it here for testing: https://godbolt.org/z/sqc75qqMv

---

[EDIT2] now this deals with the CRTP variant, without any undefined behavior and without the IsComplete workaround, just by storing the type for checking once class is complete.

```
// Will not compile, because Foo currently has incomplete type
template<IsFoo AFoo>
struct AcceptsFoo
{};
#else
template<class AFoo> // will not check IsFoo directly here...
struct AcceptsFoo
{
    using IsFooType = AFoo; // will store type on IsFootType for later checks
};
#endif

struct Foo : public AcceptsFoo<Foo> // will check only when complete
{
    int a;
    int b;
};

// Foo is now complete, and that's also fine!
static_assert(IsFoo<Foo::IsFooType>);

struct FooBar : public AcceptsFoo<FooBar> // will fail once it is complete
{
    //int a;
    int b;
};
// will fail here
static_assert(IsFoo<FooBar::IsFooType>);
```

This also works on major compilers: https://godbolt.org/z/e1Gc4Kj5n

Comment: "*just after class is finished, it is complete and matches desired IsFoo constraints.*"... and if it isn't, what then? The standard requires that if a concept produces a result against a type at some point in the program, then it always produces that result against that type. So what happens if the type *doesn't* match the "desired IsFoo constraints?"

Comment: This is IFNDR, because the value of a concept changes from one point of use to another: note that `struct Bar {AcceptsFoo<Bar> obj;};` works and in 3 major implementations causes `AcceptsFoo<Bar>` to be accepted when `Bar` *is* complete, but that might change tomorrow.

Comment: @Nicol Bolas I really don't see the issue here, as IsComplete will be evaluated to false for type Foo, and IsFoo is correctly matching the constraints (if I change them, the compiler correctly indicates which matching has failed). Could you give me an example where this would fail?

Comment: That's true @Davis Herring, struct Bar is accepted on g++10... I dont know why. Thanks for the advice. https://godbolt.org/z/Wbe7E1z4E

Comment: @David Herring I double checked and major compilers correctly reject Bar... note that my definition of AcceptsFoo allows for any incomplete type to be accepted: https://godbolt.org/z/sqc75qqMv

Comment: @igormcoelho: They do say that `IsFoo<Bar>` is `false`, but they remember that `IsFooIncomplete<Bar>` holds and don’t check it again for further use even though `Bar` is neither incomplete nor Foo.  This can easily lead to ODR violations and every other kind of madness.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the explanation @DavisHerring . I added another solution for the CRTP case, by storing the type inside the class and delaying the check for later usage, once it is complete. This one I think does not cause any undefined behavior, and it should be a practical solution (at least for my usages here...).